# @font-face not working across domains in Firefox

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, css, permissions

I am trying to use a font from typefront.com. It works in every other browser but the security restrictions in Firefox don't allow using fonts from a different domain.

I've tried creating an `.htaccess` file and adding the following snippet of code but when I try to load the site I get an internal server error page!

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mydomain.com"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gravur-CondensedBold";
  src: url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589026.eot");
  src: local("☺"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589026.woff") format("woff"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589026.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589026.svg") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gravur-CondensedLight";
  src: url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589027.eot");
  src: local("☺"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589027.woff") format("woff"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589027.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825589027.svg") format("svg");
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

here's the url: http://www.enjoythisyeah.com

Comment: can you provide the url to the page?

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be added on the `typefront.com` server, not on yours. You can ask them about that. If they don't add the header then the only solution is hosting the font on your own server.

Comment: just added the link there! thanks for the reply!

Comment: also, the font works on this site: enjoythis.co.uk but it was built by another person so I don't know how he managed to get it working...

Answer (score 0):

Use a [dataURI with a base64 encoded WOFF or SVG font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695027/how-to-use-a-data-uri-with-font-face-in-firefox) to bypass the [same-origin restriction for web fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#default-same-origin-restriction).